# Can't connect Qt with database (QMYSQL)

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

.pro

```
QT += sql
```

.h

```
explicit LoginWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
int query();
~LoginWindow();
QSqlDatabase db ;
```

.cpp

```
db = new QSqlDatabase::database("QMYSQL");
```

error:

> expected type-specifier
>        db = new QSqlDatabase::database("QSQLITE");

Comment: db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

Comment: btw, you should know that `new` is applicable only to pointers.

Comment: oh , thank you , i had fixed it .